# Homeschool moderator expects my kid to be enrolled in public school, any alternatives?

Tags: australia, education

I'm from Australia. I was aware that the homeschool moderator would come today but I've been really busy the last couple of days and was completely caught off guard. She asked to see the work and I was unprepared, unable to find the workbooks my kids had been working though. I asked it if could be rescheduled to another time but she said she was booked out. I was then asked to enrol my kids in public school within the next two weeks before leaving. We are moving to a new house 120km away in a week and my kids absolutely hate public school.

What can I do to avoid sending my kids to a public school?

Comment: This depends very heavily on the laws that apply in your jurisdiction, whether there is an appeals process and so on. I can ask about migrating this to Law.SE if you'd like.

Comment: I have asked; you may need to consider editing the question to be more generic about the homeschooling laws rather than "what can I do" (they don't do specific case legal advice).

Comment: If the ONLY reason you are home schooling them is because they hate public school, you are not doing them any good homeschooling. School isnt just about the education, its about learning how to be an adult, learning how to work with people you hate (or love) and doing things that you hate or dont see any sense in. Life is full of those situations and if you are doing things so they avoid them COMPLETELY then you are setting them up to fail when they cant avoid them. sometimes in life you just have to suck it up. sorry about that. If there are other reasons, partly ignore this rant.